# How do I set up Prettier with Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide

Tags: javascript, airbnb-js-styleguide, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier

How can I configure Airbnb's Style Guide in Prettier? I'm using VS Code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember to also to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Then, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 4):

[eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) 
 will disable all rule on formatting. It mentions [eslint-config-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) several times in the Readme file, but they didn't guarantee that it 100% follow airbnb rules.

I guess the if you want to make sure they work fine together, you have to check the rules yourself.

**Update:**

I have check the source file of `eslint-config-prettier`. Here is the list of rules can be override:

```
// The following rules can be used in some cases. See the README for more
// information. (These are marked with `0` instead of `"off"` so that a
// script can distinguish them.)

curly: 0,
"max-len": 0,
"no-confusing-arrow": 0,
"no-mixed-operators": 0,
"no-tabs": 0,
quotes: 0,
```

According to their comment, other format rules should never be used with Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) to extends a Prettier config.